# Java Bean simple Registration form

Tags: java, jsp, registration

I'm currently studying and learning webb app development and i have to build an ecommerce website as final project.

I started from registration service passing several datas from a registration form to a jsp which uses a javabean to accomplish the user insertion in a database. Something like that

```
<form action="process.jsp">
    <input type="text" name="Nome" value="Nome..." onclick="this.value=''"/>
    <br/>
    et cetera...
```

On process.jsp however i have to initialize my bean istance with all the setters of my java class

```
<%@page import="blogics.UserService"%>  
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="bflows.UserManagement"/> 
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="user"/> 
<%
    user.setNome(request.getParameter("Nome"));
    user.setCognome(request.getParameter("Cognome"));
    et cetera...
```

And then i call my method to insert user in database and even if everything is working fine (i even have entries on my database) i still have doubts cause i've never seen codes like this and i feel like i'm missing something very important but i can't figure what.

Comment: I love that part you said "i've never seen codes like this". Truly this is a deprecated pattern and must not be used in java based web application development. You must avoid the use of scriptlet. I suggest you get Head first servlet and jsp by Kathy Sierra. That will give you a good foundation in java based web app development.

Comment: Well, thankyou a lot i think i'll follow your suggestion; with "never seen code like this" i meant i look for different examples for registration on the web before posting and still nobody code something like me and i was wondering why instead of simply Copy/paste.

Comment: Ok. now i understand. The reason most code you saw online looks different is because most developers now use web frameworks. For instance, the answer given below by Anshul is based on spring framework. Not until you have not mastered jsp and servlet in depth, I will not advise you adopt the usage of framework. The very reason i recommended that book.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should avoid writing java code in your jsp file. Here is what I suggest.

Step 1: Create a POJO class

```
Class User {

    private String name;
    //setters and getters for your other form fields
}
```

Step 2: Make a controller for posting your form

```
@RequestMapping('/register')
Class RegistrationController(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    String name = user.getName();
    // In the same way you can get your other form fields
    // Now you can send these details to the database
}
```

Step 3: In your jsp file keep your field with the same name as given in POJO class, for eg-: If in POJO class the field name is **userName**, then in jsp file it will be same, **name="userName"**

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">

    <!-- This name should be same as defined in the POJO class -->
    <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
```